# firefox driver is not loaded on client machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am working with selenium web automation framework using spring, hibernate, selenium web driver. After I deployed my web app, I can able to successfully launch a Firefox browser in my local machine. When I test it with some other machine using the web app URL, FF browser is not loaded on client machine but it opens in local always. So how do we handle client-server mode with respect to selenium web driver I have done selenium hub and node register on grid stuff

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox"); 
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA); 
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(false); webDriver = new 
RemoteWebDriver(new URL(".........:5566/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

I have created one node which is running in my machine, Do I need to create more than one for client access? or Do I need to run stand alone server on clinet machine also?

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: is FireFox on default installation path?

Comment: yes..it is in default path

Comment: ok.. so are there any errors or warnings shown on console?

Comment: nothing..as usual it opens in server machine. not in client side. when i check console, i don't find any error

Comment: Can you update the qn with command used for starting node,what are the statements you see in hub and node terminals when you run the program? Would need to that to answer this

Comment: have you found how to go through it? I'm facing same problem @user3346145